# Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, data-protection

I have an Asp.NET Core app with no special setup of DataProtection stack - just AddMvc. While everything works on IISExpress/(Kestrel), on the IIS server I got this error:

```
11/23/2016 18:50:14:warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware[7]
      Error unprotecting the session cookie.
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {6d00462a-ba7f-4f65-bb36-711605de93f2} was not found in the key ring.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean& requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.CookieProtection.Unprotect(IDataProtector protector, String protectedText, ILogger logger)
11/23/2016 19:27:34:warn: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DataProtectionServices[59]
      Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits.
11/23/2016 19:27:34:warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.EphemeralXmlRepository[50]
      Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage.
11/23/2016 19:27:34:warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {27c3297d-c583-4de5-b619-489bfba62407} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
11/23/2016 19:27:35:warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware[7]
      Error unprotecting the session cookie.
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {3cbde8ae-2dba-4c84-ada3-20ba40bdff85} was not found in the key ring.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean& requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.CookieProtection.Unprotect(IDataProtector protector, String protectedText, ILogger logger)
```

It only happes for some users after sign in and not every time.
I tries to google but with no success.

Might it be some IIS configuration different on the second server? Thx.

Comment: Just answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46225867/is-it-possible-to-persist-cookies-between-visual-studio-debug-sessions/46657239#46657239)

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: I think it is not there anymore after upgrading to Asp.Net Core 2.0

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> This issue stems from a bug in IIS itself which may or may not ever be
> corrected. In order to work around the issue, it’s necessary for you
> to edit your App Pool to enable User Profile Loading. Once you set
> your App Pool to load the user profile for the application pool
> identity, the application will have permission to read and write to
> the system registry as intended.
>
> original [article](https://cypressnorth.com/programming/solved-using-memory-repository-keys-will-not-persisted-storage-asp-net-core-iis/)

In short ensure app pool loads User profile:

[image]

download either ps script or its .NET analog [here](https://github.com/poke/aspnet-ProvisionAutoGenKeys)
build it and run it as Admin like this:

```
ProvisionAutoGenKeys.exe NetCoreAppPool
```

Comment: I changed `Load User Profile = True` for Application Pool Defaults and I did not have to run ProvisionAutoGenKeys. Now keys are stored in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys` of the Application Pool identity/user.