# May I know how to fix ( No XML encryptor configured in ASP.Net Core 3.1 App )

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When I run on my local with VS 2019, everything is working fine with my window 10. After I published to my local IIS, I got this exceptions No XML encryptor configured. Key may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form ).
I tried to set Load User Profile on IIS Advanced Setting but still got errors.
Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks Jasper

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.Net Core warning No XML encryptor configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55760907/net-core-warning-no-xml-encryptor-configured)

Comment: Looks very similar to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64442358/using-an-in-memory-repository-keys-will-not-be-persisted-to-storage-after-publi#comment113958402_64442358

Comment: Hi jdweng, I tried that way also. but not solved my problems